# How are submodules characterized with respect to the isomorphism of the direct sum of multiple modules?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, examples-counterexamples, direct-sum

Consider two rings $R_1$ and $R_2$ each with their own identities, and their direct product $R_1 \times R_2$. It is well-known that the ideals of $R_1 \times R_2$ are all of the form $I_1 \times I_2$, where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are ideals of $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively.

Now, let $R$ be a ring, and $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two modules over $R$. The question arises: Are all submodules of $M_1 \oplus M_2$, up to isomorphism,  of the form $M' \oplus M''$ where $M'$ and $M''$ are submodules of $M_1$ and $M_2$ respectively?

To illustrate, let $k$ be a field. Consider the submodule $M := \{(x,x) \in k \oplus k \,|\, x \in k\}$ of $k \oplus k$. This submodule is not of the form $M' \oplus M''$ where $M'$ and $M''$ are submodules of $k$. However, $M$ is isomorphic to $k \oplus 0$ as module over $k$, and $k \oplus 0$ is a submodule of $k \oplus k$ over $k$. Therefore, this example does not serve as a counterexample to the posed question when considering isomorphism.

Comment: A starting point might be Goursat's Lemma: If $M=M_1\oplus M_2$ has projections $\pi_1,\pi_2$ and $N\le M$ is a submodule, then $N$ is the lift of the graph of an isomorphism $\pi_1(N)/(M_1\cap N)\to\pi_2(N)/(M_2\cap N)$.

Comment: I appreciate your hint, thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.

Let $R=k[x.y]/(x^2,y^2)$, where $k$ is a field. So $R$ is a four-dimensional algebra with basis $1,x,y,xy$.

Let $N=R/(xy)$. So $N$ is a three-dimensional $R$-module.

Then the map $N\to R\oplus R$ given by $n\mapsto(nx,ny)$ is injective, so $R\oplus R$ has a submodule isomorphic to $N$.

However $N$ is indecomposable (as it has a unique simple quotient), and is not isomorphic to a submodule of $R$ (as it has more than one simple submodule, but $R$ has only one).

Comment: Thank you very much for providing an excellent counterexample.